# CakePHP isn't saving long text

Tags: mysql, angularjs, json, cakephp

I'm having one big trouble. I have a controller method that receives POST requests formatted in JSON.

When I save JSON data, one field that is long text in MySQL isn't saving. But if I write short text, like "Hello World" it saves on DB. I don't know what is wrong here.

This is my Javascript code:

```
                $http({
                    url: 'http://customblahblahblah',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data:   "user_id="+ user_id +
                    "&token="+ token +
                    "&object="+angular.toJson(myobject),....
```

This is my php code:

```
public function save(){
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        if($this->checkUser($this->request->data['user_id'], $this->request->data['token'])){
            $myObject = json_decode($this->request->data['object'], true);
            if($this->MyObject->save($myObject)){
                .....
            }
     ....
           }
         }
      }
```

What is wrong here?

Because if in the property is set a text like "Hello World" it remains saved, but If I sent long text, like an newspaper article it seems to save (because doesn't throw an exception, and Model->save() is returning true) but the data isn't saved.

Comment: Obviously you have a problem with the type of db table fields where you want to save text.

Comment: It's set as long text with latin1_general_ci collation

Answer (score 1):

I've been pass with this!
The column needs to be a LONGTEXT or LONGBLOB (the most larger size you can)

If you use migrations, you need create

```
$table = $this->table('your_table');
$table->changeColumn('your_column', 'text', ['null' => true, 'limit' => MysqlAdapter::TEXT_LONG]);
$table->update();
```

You can see here: http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/migrations.html#limit-option-and-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You are decoding your json string into an object and trying to save an object in a text field. I think you need to store it in the DB as a JSON string and then decode it later on when you read it.

try:

```
if($this->MyObject->save(json_encode($myObject))){
                .....
 }
```

If you are still having trouble it could be the database datatype. In the past I have used simply `text` as the datatype for json strings.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I've checked it, but I'm still having trouble. I don't know... sometimes it works correctly, but most not. I'm using text-angular... I don't know

Comment: before you `save()` if you `debug($myObject); exit;` is it set with the data?